androidstudio running very slow to open a hello world project
I installed the androidstudio (2023.2.1 Patch1) in ubuntu. when  I open a demo app just like a Hello world simple project. it always loading for a long time.
The background task show below dialog:

What's teh reason a simple project can cost too much time? I just tinking some malware running in the background and copy my data. Wish someone help to identify what's the root cause.

Could you share your specs ?

Also check what processes are slowing down your computer using top, this should tell you what is taking up resources
